# Missing JVM metrics using prometheus jmx exporter

Tags: java, scala, jvm, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I am trying to integrate jvm metrics to my akka application. I used [prometheus jmx exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter). Instead of using the whole app and running it as java agent, I used only the exporter and integrated to my existing prometheus registry

```
import io.prometheus.jmx.JmxCollector

val jmxCollector: JmxCollector = new JmxCollector(getClass.getResourceAsStream("jmx-config.yaml"))
jmxCollector.register(prometheusRegistry)
```

I am able to see the metrics but few metrics starting with prefix jvm are missing compared to other applications which are running the exporter as java agent. Like thread metrics which are missing

```
# HELP jvm_threads_state Current count of threads by state
# TYPE jvm_threads_state gauge
jvm_threads_state{state="TERMINATED",} 0.0
jvm_threads_state{state="RUNNABLE",} 10.0
jvm_threads_state{state="TIMED_WAITING",} 11.0
jvm_threads_state{state="WAITING",} 37.0
jvm_threads_state{state="NEW",} 0.0
jvm_threads_state{state="BLOCKED",} 0.0
```

My metrics config is bare minimum and looks like this in both the applications

```
---
startDelaySeconds: 10
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
```

Could you please help me understand what could be the difference that is causing this problem.